# Do two objects at different temperatures disipate heat evenly?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Let's say I have two 1Kg cubes of Aluminum.

They are in identical rooms, and the rooms are both at 30 degrees celcius. One cube is at 50 degrees celcius, and the other is at 100 degrees celcius.

After a certain period of time, the cube which was 50 degrees is now 40 degrees. Is the cube that was 100 degrees 90 degrees after this same amount of time? Is the heat dissipation constant?

Comment: Suppose the cooler cube were at 35C initially.  Do you think it would cool to 25C in the same time that the hotter cube cooled to 90 C, even though the room is at 30C?

Comment: Suppose one of the cubes starts at 30 C. How long would it take to cool to 20 C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newtons law of cooling gives a good approximation to your problem. The temperature drop is proportional to the temperature difference. This is illustrated in this figure:
[image]

Newtons law is correct for conduction heating. A typical experiment in freshman physics concerns this and many experiments on this has been conducted. This figure shows the famous results for a cup of hot coffee.
[image]

As you can see, for a small temperature change or difference, the rate is approximately linear. You can google Newton's law of cooling for more information and the simple equation governing the cooling.

Answer (score 1):

It can be estimated that the cube with $100^\circ C$ would have about $65^\circ C$, i.e. both cubes will reach about the temperature in the middle of the initial temperature and room temperature.

Approximately, $\frac{dT}{dt} = Const \cdot (Troom - Tcube)$, i.e.the rate of the temperature change is about proportional to the temperature difference.

It is just a first estimation, as there are 3 ways of heat dissipation:

- Contact conduction - its rate is linear with respect to temperature difference.
- Air convection, that may be non linear
- Thermal radiation, that is non linear, proportional to $T^4$

Comment: I will try to gain some MathJax knowledge till next time... :-)